# Stop nginx before APT upgrades run

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt, ubuntu-16.04, unattended

How can I stop nginx before APT upgrades run in Ubuntu?

We run unattended upgrades on the server and in case there is any upgrade that will interfere with nginx I would like to stop the nginx service before doing upgrades. (E.g. an upgrade of nginx itself or something that could affect the network connectivity.)

After the upgrade has run I want nginx to launch again automatically.

This is one of multiple servers in a pool sitting behind a load balancer, so the user-facing service will not be affected by nginx being down. The web server is nginx 1.14.2 and the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: If nginx is being upgraded, apt will stop and start it, itself. You probably don't need to do anything at all. Nobody else does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Make_apt-get_remount_.2F_if_needed probably would work.

I'd give this variant a try:

```
DPkg {
    Pre-Invoke { "systemctl stop nginx"; };
    Post-Invoke { "systemctl start nginx"; };
};
```

Put this into a file and place it in `/etc/apt.conf.d`.

It will not check if the upgrade 'interferes' with your nginx intstallation, it stops it always.

Answer (score -2):

You can stop Nginx using

```
systemctl stop nginx
```

And you can start it using

```
systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: since the question involves "unattended upgrades", I doubt that a manual procedure such as this one is what is wanted here.

Comment: he is asking if it is possible to stop nginx before upgrading